# get the unique elements in a matrix and indices of it which counts more than a given value in Matlab

Tags: matlab, count, unique

I have a vector and I want to get the counts of unique elements in that vector and find the indices of the elements whose count is more than a given value

For example, let

```
A = [1,2,2,1,1,1,5,5,5,1,1,5]
[c,ia,ic] = unique(A)
c_counts = accumarray(ic,1);
```

now, I want to find the indices of values in A where c == t given value (for example t = 4).

My expected output when t = 4 will be
7,8,9,12  (the indices of 5, as 5 appears exactly 4 times), and when t = 6 the output will be 1,4,5,6,10,11 (indices of 1, as it appears exactly 6).

========================UPDATE=======================
I want to iterate over the top 5 counts only (5 highest count values). I get the counts of unique elements in cb_counts and then I iterate over the 5 highest count values to get the result.

How can I do this in matlab ?

Comment: There is no `a`. Do you mean `A`? What exactly is your expected output? State that explicitly

Comment: @SardarUsama  edited my question.

Comment: What happen if you have multiple values with the same number of occurrences? For example, if the first element would be `5` instead of `1`, and `t` is 5?

Comment: Will you be inputting t=4, 6 etc yourself? If not, what do you expect exactly to have at output?

Comment: @Adiel  in that case, I want all the indices corresponding to the multiple values.  for example, if the first element is 5 instead of 1 and t = 5, then i want indices where 1 and 5 appears.

Comment: @SardarUsama. Nope. I will not be inputting those values. Those values are based on the count result. Ideally, i will go through the count vector and based on the counts I need the result

Comment: So you want to go through all of them one by one? What if number of indices for each of them are not same (like in your case). If you provide exactly what matrix/cell/struct you're expecting at output, everything would be clear

Comment: @SardarUsama not all, I prefer the big 5.  if count of the unique elements are 1,1,1,2,5,10,20,50,50,100,100. I like to get the indices for the top 5 counts i.e. 100,100,50,50,20  only

Comment: @SardarUsama It really does not matter what data strcuture the outputs are in.  Ideally, I prefer a vector of indices.

Comment: @SardarUsama If I am going to iterate over the count (using a loop), it does not matter right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to get the count of each [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) element and [concatenate](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/horzcat.html) `c` with it. Now [sort the rows](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) to get the counts in order with their unique elements. [Iterate](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) and use [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to get relevant indices of `A` for its unique elements of top-`t` counts.

```
t = 2;   %Number of top counts
tmp = sortrows([c.' accumarray(ic,1)], -2);  
out =  arrayfun(@(x) find(A==tmp(x,1)), 1:t, 'un', 0);

%or with a conventional loop instead of arrayfun:
%out = cell(1,t)
%for k=1:t
%   out{k} = find(A==tmp(k,1));
%end
```

---

```
>> out{:}

ans =

     1     4     5     6    10    11


ans =

     7     8     9    12
```

If you want a single vector containing all the indices then `[out{:}]` will give you that.

Comment: I get error using too many inputs for `sortrows`, because `descend` is defined only for table inpot. For matrix input you can use `sortrows(..., -2)`

Comment: @Adiel No such issue for R2017a atleast

Comment: @Adiel I fixed it as per your suggestion to make it compatible for older versions. Thanks for trying that.

Comment: @SardarUsama, what should I edit, if I need to specify a value instead of the top-t counts.  For example, iif instead of the top-2 counts, I need to get the indices of all the elements with corresponding count greater than [25,50,100,200] ?

Comment: @SardarUsama, I am sorry.  Still not sure what exactly you meant by output.  As in the previous case I am fine with vectors as output.  I am trying different combinations for the $t$ value.  One possibility is use the top counts and I am thinking of another possibility of custom counts than the top counts.

Comment: @Shew `c(accumarray(ic,1)>t)` will give you the elements whose indices you need to `find`. If you need to get the indices in ascending/descending order of counts then use `sort`. Then just loop over the elements